# DbContext constructor connection string error keyword name not supported

Tags: connection-string, entity-framework-6

The [entity framework documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592674) states that I can use a named parameter when supplying my connection string:

```
public class BloggingContext : DbContext 
{ 
    public BloggingContext() 
        : base("name=BloggingCompactDatabase") 
    { 
    } 
}
```

I normally don't normally bother with the named parameter:

```
public TspDbContext()
    : base("ViktorVooey") { }
```

but I thought I'd give it a go just for confirmation:

```
   public TspDbContext()
            : base("name=ViktorVooey") { }
```

and it fails saying

> Keyword not supported : name

This is on EF6. So I'm sort of stuck between not really caring but still wanting to know "what's up with that" all the same.

Answer (score 2):

I came across your post because I had the same error. The [MSDN documentation for EF 6 DbContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) explicitly states that the 'name=' part of the constructor string parameter is supported and means:

> The name can also be passed in the form 'name=myname', in which case
>   the name must be found in the config file or an exception will be
>   thrown.

In other words the "name=" prefix forces EF to only look for a config file entry for the connection string.

So you should check that the value you pass with "name=" is actually a name key value in your config file.

For example, in the config file:

```
<add name="MyContextName" connectionString="blah blah"/>
```

In the constructor:

```
public MyContext()
            : base("name=MyContextName")
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this turned out to be an issue with Resharper.  I suspended Resharper, built and the error went away.

After I restarted Resharper the error stayed away.